How to set job parameters when using Flink SQL client?
So I tried to use SET statements but it doesn't work. The documentation never mentions how to pass in job parameters either.
For context, I'm trying to provide parameters to my custom function using FunctionContext.getJobParameter.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Can you be more specific please ? What kind of parameter you want to pass. What are you trying to achieve ? Can you give an example.

@Niko I'm trying fetch Avro schema from Confluent Schema Registry. My SQL row has 2 fields: "subject" and "data". "subject" is the schema subject, whereas "data" is schema registry encoded payload. Please don't ask why I can't use the Confluent Avro format. It's a long story. Basically, I need to pass in schema registry url and any credentials.

So you planning to use an UDF which uses Schema Registry to deserialize avro data in Kafka ? I'm quite sure that SET statement will not work because it's build for Flink built-in configuration parameters. You probably need some kind of workaround.

So if I can't use job parameters then the only other way I can think of is environment variables. Is it the best alternative?

Or hardcode in your UDF the Registry arguments. Not the best way. Maybe there is a way to pass arguments to a jar with your UDF something like -D
